# How can I delete both the user and their post at the same time in my Flask App

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In my head this is supposed to be easy but it's challenging me a little bit. I am trying to delete a user along with their post on a blog. However, I am not having much success with this.

Here is my deleted user route:

```html
@views.route('/deleteuser/<id>')
@login_required
def deleteuser(id):
   user = User.query.get_or_404(id)
   try:
        db.session.delete(user)

   except:
        db.session.delete(user)
    db.session.commit()
    flash ('The user was successfully deleted', 'success')
    return redirect (url_for('views.users'))
```

Here is my delete post Id:

```
@views.route('/delete/<id>')
@login_required
def delete(id):
   post = Post.query.get_or_404(id)
   try:
        os.unlink(os.path.join(current_app.root_path,'static/assets/images/' + post.image))
        db.session.delete(post)
    except:
        db.session.delete(post)
db.session.commit()
flash ('Post deleted succesfully', 'success')
return redirect (url_for('views.dashboard'
```

Is there a way I can deleted the user along with the post?

Again, I am still new to this so please be kind.

Answer (score 1):

What you would need, is a **"one-to-many relationship"**.

When you want to delete the user, simply go ahead and do a **cascade delete** and voila! both the user and his/her related post(s) would be deleted.

I am assuming that you don't know about **one-to-many realtionship**. If you know and only want to know about the deletion process, take a look at **STEP (4)**.

Anyways, Consider the following procedures to create a one-to-many relationship in **flask-sqlalchemy** and how to perform a cascade deletion:

To start off with, I have a **`User`** and **`Post`** model like so:

```py
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
            ...
            ...

class Post(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
            ...
            ...
```

Now, its time to decide a relationship. Logically, one user can create many posts, right? So the most apt relationship would be to use **one-to-many relationship**. Let's go ahead and implement that:

**1) Declare the relation from the User Model** : Since its the Users who write the Posts, we must begin declaring relations from the User's side (conveniently and logically correct). Just add this line inside the **`User`** model:

```py
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
            ...
            ...
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='written_by')
```

Let's break this down a little bit. `posts` here, is a pseudo-column, which means **this column does not exist in the `User` model**. Its only there to create a relationship. `'Post'` is the name of the model we want to attach the relationship with. In our case, its the `Post` model. Finally, `backref` is used to refer back to the **`User`** model. We will take a look at this, shortly.

**2) Create a `user_id` column in Post** : To access the columns of **`User`** from **`Post`**, we must have a `ForeignKey` of **id** from **User**. Let's declare that.  Just add this line in the **`Post`** model:

```py
class Post(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
            ...
            ...
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeginKey('user.id'))
```

Lets see what this line does. This code simply creates a column called `user_id` which contains the `id` form **`User`** model. Please note that here, `'user.id'` is actually referring to **id from User model** and writing `'User.id'` instead will return error. **Flask-Sqlalchemy has such syntactical irregularities.** Stay frosty!

**3) Insert the data** : I am going to insert some data into **`User`** model. It is a straight-forward process and I believe you know this as well. I am going to add dummy data through my python shell (assume that I have a required column called username, for convenience):

```
>>> user1 = User(username='John', .., ...)
>>> user2 = User(username='Joe', .., ...)
>>> db.session.add_all([user1, user2])
>>> db.session.commit()
```

Now, let me add some **posts.** Lets imaging that `user1` has written 2 posts while `user2` has only written 1 post.

```
>>> post1 = Post(title='I like Python',.., .., written_by=user1)
>>> post2 = Post(title='I like C',.., .., written_by=user1)
>>> post3 = Post(title='Redis, Really?',.., .., written_by=user2)
>>> db.session.add_all([post1, post2, post3])
>>> db.session.commit()
```

Carefully observe couple of things here. While inserting the data into **`Post`** model, we pass in the required columns and then, finally we make use of the `backref` to assign this post to the respective user (since this is a **one-to-many** model). `backref` accepts **object / instance**. Now, remember that we have declared the `backref` as **written_by** and that we have already created the `user1` instance. This is the justification of `written_by=user1` in the above code.

**[OPTIONAL]**
Our relationship is crafted and the tables are ready! If you type in the following, you should get the following results:

```
>>> post1.written_by.username  # testing backref
'John'

>>> post3.written_by.username  # testing backref
'Joe'

>>> user1.posts   # should return us the list of post objects written by user1
[<Post object>, <Post object>]

>>> user1.posts[0].title
'I like Python'
```

**4) Cascade Deletion** : Now, in order to delete a **user and its corresponding posts**, all you have to do is add `cascade='all, delete'` in the **User relationship**:

```py
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
            ...
            ...
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='written_by', cascade='all, delete') # <--- edit here
```

Now, lets go ahead and delete the user `John`. This should delete all his written posts as well:

```
>>> delete_user = User.query.filter_by(username='John').first()
>>> db.session.delete(delete_user)
>>> db.session.commit()
```

**NOTE:** If you tried to delete any of the posts instead of the user, then only that post will be deleted and the user would still exist.

So, long story short: You need to use a **one-to-many realtionship** and then use a **cascade deletion from the table where you have declared relationship.**